# Why isn't my file being read in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure why my file isn't being read in my C# program. When I run it, it just gives a 0 in the textbox and doesn't list any names. I wonder if its a problem with something else and it is reading the file correctly. Thanks for the help in advance everyone!

Here is the CustomerDA class that calls the file and which I'm not sure exactly if its correct:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;


namespace CustomerList
{
public static class CustomerDA
{
    private const string dir = @"Z:\Desktop\Windows 7 Files\C#.net\CustomerList\CustomerList";
    private const string path = dir + "CustomerDat.txt";

    public static List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        StreamReader textIn =
            new StreamReader(
                new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

        List<Customer> custList = new List<Customer>(); // this create the list to add the Customers to.
        while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string row = textIn.ReadLine();
            string[] columns = row.Split(',');
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.Name = columns[0];
            customer.Email = columns[1];
            customer.CreditRating = Convert.ToInt16(columns[2]);
            customer.City = columns[3];
            customer.Zip = columns[4];
        }

        textIn.Close();

        // use the method to read found in the book as an example on page 677
        // The file to read can be found on Moodle CustomerDat.txt
        // I also placed a copy in this project.


        //once all of the Customers have been read into the List return the list
        return custList;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the Form1.cs, I'm not sure if I am calling it correctly or not. Everything seems correct to me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomerList
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<Customer> ourCustomers = new List<Customer>();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // call the CustomerDa Class and read all of the Customers from the file and return the list back here
        ourCustomers = CustomerDA.GetAllCustomers();
    }

    private void btnShowGood_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numGoodCustomers = 0;

        // loop through all of the customers returned from the file
        foreach (Customer cust in ourCustomers)
        {
            // see if the customer has a rating > 8
            if(cust.CreditRating > 8)
            {
                // add the name to the listbox
                lstGoodCustomers.Items.Add(cust.Name);
                // add one to the count of good customers
                numGoodCustomers ++;

            }

        }

        // Update the form with the number of good Customers
        txtNumGoodCustomers.Text = numGoodCustomers.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Learn to use the debugger.

Answer (score 4):

You never add to the list while reading, so it is always empty. Add `custList.Add(customer)` to the end of the loop.

```
private const string dir = @"Z:\Desktop\Windows 7 Files\C#.net\CustomerList\CustomerList";
private const string path = Path.Combine(dir, "CustomerDat.txt");

List<Customer> custList = new List<Customer>(); // this create the list to add the Customers to.
while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
{
   string row = textIn.ReadLine();
   string[] columns = row.Split(',');
   Customer customer = new Customer();
   customer.Name = columns[0];
   customer.Email = columns[1];
   customer.CreditRating = Convert.ToInt16(columns[2]);
   customer.City = columns[3];
   customer.Zip = columns[4];
   custList.Add(customer); //This was missing
}
```

As @Gusman noted (added to my answer for completeness) you need to use `Path.Combine` instead of '+' as well, your path is invalid as is.

Comment: Lol, with our two responses we get a full answer XD

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's easy, use ALWAYS Path.Combine to join two path elements.

Why I said that?

Look, you have dir = @"Z:\Desktop\Windows 7 Files\C#.net\CustomerList\CustomerList" and path = dir + "CustomerDat.txt", so path is @"Z:\Desktop\Windows 7 Files\C#.net\CustomerList\CustomerListCustomerDat.txt".

You are missing an "\", using Path.Combine avoids those problems.

Comment: +1 Didn't catch that one, nice!